# Installing procps in postgres:11.10 docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, apt-get

I am using postgres:11.10 image from dockerhub and I am looking to install the 'procps' package on the image prior to running the image. To that end I have added `RUN apt-get install procps` in my Dockerfile.

However, while building the image I get the following:

```
E: Unable to locate package procps
ERROR: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install procps' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

My question is, when executing `RUN apt-get install procps`, how does Docker determine which debian repositories to consult while searching for packages? Does the docker installation on the host determine the debian repositories to consult or is it determined by the repositories configured in the base image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the apt package sources and then install the `procps` package.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:11.10
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y procps
```

Comment: that was it! Thank you. Just curious does this mean that a docker image does not have an index of available packages by default?

Comment: It does but it might be older one without procps package info. Always better to apt update before installing/upgrading any new package.